# HTML content not visible

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a dropdown button on my website, but it just wants to stay invisible for some reason. When I inspect the page from my browser and hover over the mentioned content, the boundaries and position are marked the way intended, but somehow nothing is rendered
Here is HTML:

```
<span class="dropdown">
    <a class="basic" href="documents.php">Documents</a>
    <span class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="documents.php">BUTTON</a>
        <a href="documents.php">BUTTON</a>
        <a href="documents.php">BUTTON</a>
    </span>
</span>
```

Only the link with class "basic" shows up. The rest is not rendered. 
That's the CSS that goes with it:

```
.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color:rgb(70,90,120);
    width:100%;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    display: block;
    font-size:200%;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {display: block;}
```

These are the inherited styles:

```
text-align: center;
color: white;
font-family: Helvetica;
```

Comment: It's invidible because of display: none; on .dropdown-content

Comment: Your links are inside the `<span>` with the class `dropdown-content`, according to your CSS, this class has the `display` property to `none`

Comment: Depending on how the rest of the page is set up, it might be being rendered behind other elements. In that case you might want to set the z-index.

Comment: The display goes to block when the link is hovered. Also I set it to block by default for testing purposes. Thats not the case. EDIT: Played with z index as well, but still nothing is showing up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is working, see below.

Maybe you cannot "see" the element because it is inheriting that `color:white`..? Are you defining a background color other than white?

```css
.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color:rgb(70,90,120);
    width:100%;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    display: block;
    font-size:200%;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {display: block;}
```

```html
<span class="dropdown">
    <a class="basic" href="documents.php">Documents</a>
    <span class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="documents.php">BUTTON</a>
        <a href="documents.php">BUTTON</a>
        <a href="documents.php">BUTTON</a>
    </span>
</span>
```

Comment: Thats not it. I've changed the color as well for testing purposes, but nothing renders.

Comment: You must have some other js or css that is causing it - you can see your very code working above right? Is it somewhere that we can see, or could you put the whole code somewhere for us to see?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem... I had this menu inside my header tag, and in my header css I had set

```
overflow: hidden;
```

for some reason... I should've checked that. Thanks everyone for your help!